# Universal property of generating set for vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and $S$ a non-empty subset of $V$. We say that $S$ generates $V$ if every $v\in V$ can be written as finite $F$-linear combination of elements of $S$.

I want to express the above definition of generating set in terms of universal property. My question is whether the following is the universal property of $S$ (generating set) and how to prove that it is equivalent to above definition? Just hint is sufficient, I will try to write complete proof.

> We say that $S$ generates $V$ if the following holds: any map $\varphi$ from $S$ into any vector space $W$ extends to a linear map $\varphi_1$ from $V$ into/onto $W$.

Comment: Do you wanna qualify that $\varphi$ be a homomorphism?

Comment: no, in vector space category, morphisms should be linear maps (it was initial typo from me, sorry for inconvenience, I corrected it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The universal property you wrote (leaving out any assertion about $\varphi_1$ being injective or surjective) is equivalent to $S$ being linearly independent, not generating $V$.  You want to say instead that any $\varphi$ extends to *at most one* linear map $\varphi_1$ (again, with no condition that $\varphi_1$ is injective or surjective).  The hard direction of the proof is that if $S$ has this property, then $S$ generates $V$.  To prove this direction, you need to give an example of a $\varphi$ for which $\varphi_1$ is not unique, assuming $S$ does not generate $V$.  To do this, let $U$ be the subspace generated by $S$, $W=V/U$, and $\varphi=0$.

Comment: if $\varphi_1$ is onto linear map, will it not imply that $S$ generates $V$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  What choice of $\varphi:S\to W$ are you making?  The basic problem with your condition is that if $S$ is not linearly independent, then for most choices of $\varphi$ there will not exist _any_ linear extension $\varphi_1$.

Comment: OK, I will make it precise: let $S$ be a subset of $V$ satisfying following property: given any map from $S$ to a vector space $W$, it extends to a linear map from $V$ *onto* $W$ (i.e. $\varphi_1\colon V\rightarrow W$ is surjective linear map). Then is this (property) equivalent to say that $S$ generates $V$?

Comment: That condition is not true for _any_ subset of _any_ vector space.  You can always choose $W$ to have larger dimension than $V$, and then there can't exist any linear surjection $V\to W$.

Comment: OK, I got what you want to explain. (Can you give a hint then for universal property of generating set? Sorry, if this is not appropriate)

Comment: perhaps third line *...at most one ...* of your answer is the universal property of generating set, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, everything after my first sentence is about characterizing generating sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wofsey for the clarification in definition. +1